# make a total with 2 models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have a table named `seances` with 3 fields(id, type_seance, price)

[image]

Then, I also have a table named `payments` with 4 fields (id, fk_type_seance, number_seance, total)

When, I add a recording in my form `Payment`

[image]

[image]

If, I select the type of seance `Theoretical` (the price is de 100$) and that I enter 2 like number of seance the total is 200$.

I have a problem in my Controller Payment , How to adapt my field price and fk_type_seance ?? To retrieve the total?

```
$data['total'] = $request->price->fk_type_seance * $request->number_seance;
```

Here is my code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {      

        $request->validate([
           'fk_type_seance' => 'required',
           'number_seance' => 'required',
           'total' => 'required'

         ]);

        $exists = Payment
                     ::where('fk_type_seance', $request->get('fk_type_seance'))
                     ->where('number_seance', $request->get('number_seance'))
                     ->where('total', $request->get('total'))
                     ->count();

       if (!$exists)
       {
            $data = $request->all(); 

            $data['total'] = $request->price->fk_type_seance * $request->number_seance;
            //Payment::create($request->all());
            Payment::create($data);
            return redirect()->route('payments.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->route('payments.index')
                ->with('error', 'doublon');

        }   

    }
```

For now, here is my form Payment, I have a problem with the total.
[image]

Edit **code jtwes**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {      

        $request->validate([
           'fk_type_seance' => 'required',
           'number_seance' => 'required',
           'total' => 'required'

         ]);

        $exists = Payment::where('fk_type_seance', $request->get('fk_type_seance'))->where('number_seance', $request->get('number_seance'))->where('total', $request->get('total'))->count();

       if (!$exists){
            $seance = Seance
                  ::where('id','=',$request->get('fk_type_seance'))
                  ->first();
            $seance = $request->all(); 
            if ($seance) $total = $seance->price * $request->number_seance;
            Payment::create($seance);
            return redirect()->route('payments.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
        }

        else{
            return redirect()->route('payments.index')
                ->with('error', 'doublon');

        }   

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is where the problem begins:

```
$data['total'] = $request->price->fk_type_seance * $request->number_seance;
```

Here you are calculating the `total` based on the product of the `$request->price->fk_type_seance` and `$request->number_seamce` but in your request validation you don't have a `price` variable.. and even if so it doesn't make any sense to multiply and id (`fk_type_seance`) by a quantity. What you should multiply is the `price` and the quantity.

So, replace that with:

```
// first find your seance instance:
$seance = Seance::find($request->fk_type_seance);
// then calculate the total
$data['total'] = $seance->price * $request->number_seance;
```

Then you get the correct `total` amount.

Also you should make additional validations to the request payload. Here I'm adding an [exists](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-exists) validation to check if the `fk_type_seance` has a matching id in the `seances` table but first making it sure to be an `integer`. Also, how do you receive the total, you calculate it in the view? Anyway, it should look like this:

```
$request->validate([
   'fk_type_seance' => 'required|integer|exists:seances,id',
   'number_seance'  => 'required|integer',
   'total'          => 'required|numeric',
 ]);
```

So your function now is like the following. Notice that I used the [`$request->only(...)` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input) instead of the `->all()` to get only the desired data (for security reasons):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{      
    $request->validate([
       'fk_type_seance' => 'required|integer|exists:seances,id',
       'number_seance'  => 'required|integer',
       'total'          => 'required|numeric',
     ]);

    $data = $request->only(['fk_type_seance', 'number_seance', 'total']);

    $exists = Payment
          ::where('fk_type_seance', $data['fk_type_seance'])
          ->where('number_seance', $data['number_seance'])
          ->where('total', $data['total'])
          ->count();

   if ( ! $exists)
   {
        $seance = Seance::find($data['fk_type_seance']);
        $data['total'] = $seance->price * $data['number_seance'];
        Payment::create($data);

        return redirect()
           ->route('payments.index')
           ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect()
            ->route('payments.index')
            ->with('error', 'doublon');
    }   

}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot HCK for your explanations. My problem is solved, thank you ! ^^

Comment: @user11124425 glad to help. Have a nice day.

Comment: Also @user11124425 I did some little changes to improve the code.. take a closer look to spot them.

Comment: Here, I Think ? `$seance = Seance::find($data['fk_type_seance']);
        $data['total'] = $seance->price * $data['number_seance'];`

Comment: Yeah sort of, you can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57469384/revisions)

Comment: Ah, Yess... Thank you ^^

Comment: Can I ask you a question please? I am stuck since 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get your seance before calculating... 
Something like this:

```
$seance = Seance::where('id','=',$request->get('fk_type_seance))->first();
if ($seance) $total = $seance->price * $request->number_seance;
```

Comment: I have tried this, but I always stuck... Do you have an idea please??  `if (!$exists){
            $seance = Seance::where('id','=',$request->get('fk_type_seance'))->first();
            $seance = $request->all(); 
            if ($seance) $total = $seance->price * $request->number_seance;
            Payment::create($seance);
            return redirect()->route('payments.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
        }` I have edited my first message

Comment: you are overwriting $seance directly. That makes no sense...
delete $seance = $request->all();
After that Payment::create([

]); with the needed fields...